# Properties of eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A :=\begin{pmatrix}  
          5 &−6 &0\\
         2 &−2& 0  \\
          0 &0 &2  \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Determine an eigenvector of the matrix that is perpendicular to the vector $\mathbf v = (1, −4, 1).$

I think I need to first determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. Then I can use that a linear combination of eigenvectors of eigenvalue $λ$ is again an eigenvector of eigenvalue $λ$. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the eigenvector $\mathbf v$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $λ$ we have
$$A\mathbf v=λ\mathbf v$$
Then:
$$A\mathbf v-λ\mathbf v=(A-λI)\mathbf v=0$$
Equation has a nonzero solution if and only if
$$\det(A-λI)=0$$
$$\det(A-λI)=\begin{vmatrix} 5-λ& -6& 0 \\  2& -2-λ& 0\\ 0& 0& 2-λ\end{vmatrix} $$$$=-λ^3+5λ^2-8λ+4=-(λ-1)(λ^2-4λ+4)=-(λ-1)(λ-2)^2=0$$

$\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$ with multiplicity $2$ are the eigenvalues.

For each eigenvalue, look for the associated eigenvector. $( A' − I ) \mathbf X = \mathbf{0}$. If $\lambda_1=1$ then $$\begin{pmatrix}
 4& -6& 0 \\
  2& -1& 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
 x \\
  y\\
 z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\
  0\\
 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Solving the system you will find a vector of components, for example, $\mathbf v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)\ne \mathbf 0$. If $\mathbf v_1\cdot \mathbf v =0$ then $\mathbf v_1 \perp \mathbf v$. Same steps for $\lambda_2=2$.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I will add a couple of words: in this case you definitely want to exploit the fact that you already know one of the eigenvectors (and the corresponding eigenvalue), so you just need to compute the remaining eigenvectors by looking for the eigenvectors of the two by two matrix on the top left corner. Computing the characteristic polynomial of a two by two matrix is of course particularly easy, as the coefficients are given by the trace and the determinant.

Comment: Once you know the eigenvalues of the smaller matrix, you'll notice that there is one eigenspace of dimension two, so it must intersect the plane perpendicular to the given vector: this means you only need to compute one egenvector. Once you do so, it is easy to guess the correct eigenvector perpendicular to the given one, the vector (2,1,2), although of course, you can always compute the intersection between the eigenspace and the plane perpendicular to your given vector if you cannot see the answer immediately.

Comment: @milore I greatly appreciate your clarifications. Unfortunately, I am just a simple high school teacher who remembers a little of what he did a long time ago. Many of my school colleagues do not even know what an eigenspace is and many other things. I have done my best. I thank you again by pointing out that with this technique you have to reject obviously the null vector.